# Bring up the keyboard on windows 10 tablet mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, gestures, tablet-mode

I'm using a tablet with windows 10. I'm using a fullscreen app that requires keyboard to successfully interact with it, but there is nothing in the app itself that brings up an onscreen keyboard. Is there a way to set windows to bring up the keyboard through a gesture or a corner movement of some kind? On a side note, I used to use an app called splashtop that streams desktop environments to tablets, and that app has a permanent onscreen button to bring up a virtual keyboard at any time. I would love to make that happen on windows tablet mode too. Thanks.

Comment: Which Tablet?  My experience is entirely different with my Surface Pro 3, Surface Pro 4, and Surface Book.

Comment: A dirt hack is something like the following: [here](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=106)

Comment: @Ramhound does the surface line have a keyboard button? I'm talking about an ancient app from like 2003 that probably doesn't use the keyboard apis. I'm using a chuwi hipro 8. I know how to bring up the keyboard normally in normal apps, just specific fullscreen games don't work. I don't have access to any of the normal windows UI while inside the app. It's full screen.